# What's the difference between the python-django and django-rainbow charms?

Tags: juju, cloud, django

I'm looking to deploy my Django application using juju. Quickly looking over the charm store, I noticed there are two different charms to do this. One simply named `python-django` and another called `django-rainbow`.

The `python-django` charm is described like:

> This charm will install Django. It can also install your Django
>   project and his dependencies from either a template or from a version
>   control system. It can also link your project to a database and sync
>   the schemas. This charm also come with a Fabric fabfile to interact
>   with the deployement in a cloud aware manner.

And `django-rainbow` like so:

> Django-rainbow is a full-fledged Django web project deployment charm.
>   One can deploy many projects onto a single instance by maintaining
>   individual config files pertaining to the project. Django-rainbow is a
>   safe and convenient platform for development or production web server
>   management. Web sites are updated instantly using mercurial based
>   versioning. Your django-rainbow project file can be stored for future
>   use, allowing anyone using juju a fail safe method to  develop and
>   deploy your project without creating conflicting structure.
>   Django-rainbow is a "Set it and forget it" platform leaving
>   development issues with the developers :)

What are the differences and why would I choose one over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What are the differences and why would I choose one over the other?

Both charms are similar in term of functionality but differ in there completeness.

Database support:

django-rainbow support only mysql and not as a relation but installed in the
same unit that the django project is installed.

python-django support only postgresql for now. But mongodb and mysql are on the way (see https://code.launchpad.net/~patrick-hetu/+junk/python-django-mysql-support)

WSGI:

django-rainbow support apache2 and you need to configure your vhost manually in the charm's configuration file.

python-django works with a wsgi relation for now only a Gunicorn subordinate implement the interface.

Only in the django-rainbow charm:

- you can configure the domain name of your django.contrib.sites app.

Only in the python-django charm:

- a website relation (for load balancing for example)
- a Memcached relation
- an upgrade hook (upgrades packages, requirements.txt, pip, etc)
- a Juju compatible fabfile to interact with your Django deployment
- it can be extended via application subordinate charms (see the section in the README)

Low level:

- the django-rainbow charm is written in bash while the python-django charm is written in python.